# How to get a flow to wait for task completion?

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks

I have a flow that needs to wait on "Initiate Background Check Task" completion before going to the next stage/step.  The task is assigned to a queue so that there is a team of employees who can complete the task. If I create a field for "Initiate Background Check Complete Date" is it possible to pause the flow until the field has a value? Any advice?

[image: flow builder screen]

Comment: You can accomplish this by creating a separate record-triggered flow. Within this flow, you can verify if the "Initiate Background Check Complete Date" field has a value before proceeding with your subsequent process.

Comment: this is what Flow Orchestrator was designed for